# Infinite dimensional dg-manifolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, higher-category-theory, derived-algebraic-geometry

In [Def 2.5.1 in " Derived Quot schemes"](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9905174) by Ciocan-Fontanine and Kapranov, we can find the notion of dg-manifolds.

In detail, let $X$ be a dg-scheme over $k$ ($k$ : an algebraic closed field of $ch(k) = 0$), then $X = (X^0, \mathcal{O}_X^{\bullet})$ is called a dg-manifold if $X^0$ is a smooth algebraic variety and $\mathcal{O}^{\bullet}_X$ is locally isomorphic (as graded sheaves ) to $\operatorname{Sym}_{\mathcal{O}_X^0}(\bigoplus_i Q^{-i})$ where the degree $-i$-part $Q^{-i}$ are locally free sheaf on $X^0$ of finite ranks.

(a) Can we consider an analogous definition in the case $X^0$ is infinite dimensional or $Q^{-i}$ is infinite rank ?
(Edit: Any reference is also welcome.)

(b) Moreover, if we can define that notion, are there any conditions such that  an infinite dg-manifold can be quasi-isomorphic to some dg-manifolds  defined by Ciocan-Fontanine and Kapranov.

At least, I will treat the example whose classical part is finite dimensional and their tangent complexes have finite cohomology at each point.
(Edit: I am also considering fixing constructions of derived quot schemes by them because that constructions are failed according to [introduction of this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.03021))

Any comments and suggesting references are welcome !

**Edit**: Can we also extend (b) in dg-stacks ?

In particular, I'm interested the following case:

Let $A$ be a graded $k$-algebra and $V = \oplus_{i \geq 0} V_i$ be graded $k$-vector space (I assume that each $V_i$ is finite dimensional but $V$ is not necessarily. ).

We consider $L := \oplus_{i \geq 0} L^i := \oplus_{i \geq 0} {Hom}_{k-gr}(A^{\otimes n} \otimes_k V,V)$.
Then, we have a dg-lie algebra structure on $L$.
In detail, the. differential $d : L_n \rightarrow L_{n+1}$ is given by $d\mu(a_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes a_{n+1} \otimes v ) = \sum_i (-1)^{n-i}\mu(\cdots \otimes a_ia_{i+1} \otimes \cdots \otimes v)$. The bracket is given by commutators of compositions of linear maps.
We also have the group action of $G = \prod GL(V_i)$ on $L$ by conjugates(Then, the Lie algebra of $G$ is $L_0$).

Next, we consider $L_1 := Spec(Sym(L_1^{\vee}))$.
Then, we have a bundle of curved dg lie-algebra $\mathcal{L} = \oplus_{i>1} \mathcal{L}_i = \oplus_{i>1} L_i \times L_1$.
The curvature map is given by $f(-) = d(-) + \frac{1}{2}[-,-]$.
The differential on the fiber $\mu$ is given by $d(-) + [\mu,-]$.
The bracket is equal to that of $L$.

Finally, $\mathcal{L}$ descends to $[L_1/G]$.

What I want to study is the dg-stack $(\mathcal{X}=[L_1/G], \mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{X}}^\bullet= Sym(\mathcal{L}[1])^\vee)$ (cf. [Section 1 in this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.1884))

<s>I am interested in the case of dg-stacks constructed from dg Lie algebras (i.e, for any given $L := \oplus_{i \geq 0 }L_i$, the underlying stack is $\mathcal{X}= [L_1/  \text{exp}(L_0)]$ and the corresponding sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{X}}^\bullet$ of dg-algebras on $\mathcal{X}$ is a descent of the sheaf of dg-algebras on $L_1$. From this construction, $(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{O}^{\bullet}_{\mathcal{X}})$ can be called a "infinity dimensional smooth dg manifold" when $\mathcal{X}$ is infinite dimensional or $\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{X}}^\bullet$ is generated by infinite rank bundles as above. See, also [Section 1 in this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.1884)).</s>

My question is the following: When the the classical part of $(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{O}^{\bullet}_{\mathcal{X}})$ is finite dimensional and has tangent complexes with finite dimensional cohomology at each point, is this quasi-isomorphic to a smooth dg-stack defined by Ciocan-Fontanine and Kapranov in [page 31 in "Derived Hilbert schemes"](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0005155)?

**Edit(5/9)**: In the above case, I especially interested in when both $L_1$ and $G$ are infinite dimensional.
Then, we may be able to replace the structure dg-sheaves $\mathcal{O}^{\bullet}_{[L_1/G]}$ with $Sym_{\mathcal{O}_{[L_1/G]}}(Q^{'-i})$ with each $Q^{'-i}$ finite rank if we consider replacing the corresponding bundles on $L_1$.
However, I have no idea how can $[L_1/G]$ be replaced with a finite dimensional model (i.e, $[L'_1/G']$ with $L'_1,G'$ finite dimensional).

**Edit(5/7)**: In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2301.00962), dg-stacks of logarithmic flat connections is treated. By using bundles of curved dgla, the dg-moduli stack is constructed. But, it is infinite type (in detail, the gauge group is infinite dimensional). The author construct a replacement which is a finite dimensional model.
His approach seems to depend on the subject he is dealing with.
Can we make such replacements in more general situations ?

Comment: Yes, you can relax both those conditions and you will still have a derived scheme. It's then possible for those to be quasi-isomorphic to dg-manifolds - for instance an infinite product of dg-manifolds quasi-isomorphic to a point will still be quasi-isomorphic to a point. For affine dg-manifolds, your conditions should also be sufficient.

Comment: You mean that infinite affine dg-manifolds with our conditions (i.e., having a finite dim classical part and tangent complexes with finite cohomology) are quasi-isomorphic to Ciocan-Fontanine and Kapranov's dg-manifolds ? 
If so, are their any good references ?

Comment: I don't know if anyone's written it down, but the argument is just to construct a finite resolution by hand, exploiting Noetherianity and quasi-compactness. Start by forming a finite quasi-free resolution $F$ of $A$, inductively adding generators to kill the lowest homology of $cone(F->A)$, then at the final stage lift a projective $H_0A$-module by localising $F_0 $ if necessary to ensure the resolution terminates.

Comment: It seems that the argument you provided would work well in the case of infinite affine DG manifolds. I will try to write down a proof. However, I am also curious about whether an infinite smooth DG stack obtained from the Maurer-Cartan locus of a dg-Lie algebra is quasi-isomorphic to the definition of smooth DG stacks given by Ciocan-Fontanine and Kapranov when the dg stack has a finite classical part and tangent complexes with finite cohomology at each point.

Comment: A DGLA on its own won't give a DG stack, as you can only exponentiate $L^0$ infinitesimally.

Comment: The dg-stack I want to study is constructed from bundles of curved dg-lie algebras on $L^1$.In partcular, I am interested in $L$ which is related to A-infinity actions(, as written in the above  edited question).

Comment: For dg-stacks, it's rarer for such replacements to exist, but the basic condition you want is for quasi-coherent sheaves on the underlying underived stack to have vanishing positive cohomology, so a similar argument works. An example would be a quotient stack of an affine scheme by a reductive group.

Comment: You mean that a replacement exists in the above example which  is a dg-stack constructed by using bundles of curved dgla on $L_1$ ? Then, how can we perform the similar argument ? I am not sure whether the structure sheaf is think of as a dga like affine dg-schemes.

Comment: The rough idea would be to first lift the dg category of vector bundles, but I haven't checked any details.

Comment: What does 'lift the dg category of vector bundles' refer to ?

Comment: If we can "lift the dg category", I am not sure whether we can replace the underlying stack $[L_1/G]$ with a finite dimensional model $[L'_1/G']$ (i.e., both L'_1 and G' are finite dimensional.).

Comment: The aim would be to take $G'=G$. As a starting point, every smooth affine atlas of the underived truncation is the truncation of an atlas for the derived stack (obstructions vanish), but you would want to lift if $G$-equivariantly.